# Is Octopress suitable for non-pure-blog site?

Tags: web, github, octopress

I want create a website for my studio and found the Octopress + Github is attractive. Below is the structure draft of the site.

```
index
|-games
|-blog
|-....
```

Everything seldom change except the blog. The problem is I didn't fount any non-pure-blog site use Octopress + Github and I have little knowledge about building a site. I'm not sure whether Octopress can satisfy my need and how. Anybody has experience with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Octopress might not be the best choice here, because :

- As the official tag line goes, it is a blogging framework for hackers.
- Static frameworks have some limitations

That said, you can do a fair amount of customization as evident from [here](http://www.adrianartiles.com/) and [here](http://photography.bastardsbook.com/) .